# How can you display a multi-line column header using the Flex Spark Data Grid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, flex-spark

How can you display a multi-line column header using the Flex Spark Data Grid for Flex 4.5?

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon Constantiner's answer, you'll have to create a custom `HeaderRenderer` and set the `Label`'s `maxDisplayedLines` to 2. Here's a [sample renderer I found](http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/adding-an-icon-to-the-header-for-a-spark-datagrid/):

**MyRenderer.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--

ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
Copyright 2010 Adobe Systems Incorporated
All Rights Reserved.

NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.

-->

<!--- 

The DefaultGridHeaderRenderer class defines the default header renderer 
for the columns of a Spark DataGrid control.

<p>Subclasses defined in MXML can redefine the values of the <code>labelDisplay</code>
and <code>sortIndicator</code> properties.</p>

@see spark.components.DataGrid
@see spark.components.GridColumnHeaderGroup
@see spark.components.gridClasses.GridItemRenderer

@langversion 3.0
@playerversion Flash 10
@playerversion AIR 2.0
@productversion Flex 4.5
-->

<s:GridItemRenderer minWidth="21" minHeight="21"
                    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!--- The default value of the <code>sortIndicator</code> property.
        It must be an IFactory for an IVisualElement.        

        <p>This value is specified in a <code>fx:Declaration</code> block and can be overridden
        by a declaration with <code>id="defaultSortIndicator"</code>
        in an MXML subclass.</p>

        @langversion 3.0
        @playerversion Flash 10
        @playerversion AIR 2.0
        @productversion Flex 4.5
        -->
        <fx:Component id="defaultSortIndicator">
            <s:Path data="M 3.5 7.0 L 0.0 0.0 L 7.0 0.0 L 3.5 7.0" implements="spark.components.gridClasses.IGridVisualElement">
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import spark.components.DataGrid;
                        import spark.components.Grid;

                        /**
                         *  @private
                         */
                        public function prepareGridVisualElement(grid:Grid, rowIndex:int, columnIndex:int):void
                        {
                            const dataGrid:DataGrid = grid.dataGrid;
                            if (!dataGrid)
                                return;

                            const color:uint = dataGrid.getStyle("symbolColor");
                            arrowFill1.color = color;
                            arrowFill2.color = color;
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>

                <s:fill>
                    <s:RadialGradient rotation="90" focalPointRatio="1">    
                        <!--- @private -->
                        <s:GradientEntry id="arrowFill1" color="0" alpha="0.6" />
                        <!--- @private -->
                        <s:GradientEntry id="arrowFill2" color="0" alpha="0.8" />
                    </s:RadialGradient>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Path>
        </fx:Component>

        <!--- Displays the renderer's label property, which is set to the column's <code>headerText</code>.
        It must be an instance of a <code>TextBase</code>, like <code>s:Label</code>.

        <p>This visual element is added to the <code>labelDisplayGroup</code> by the renderer's
        <code>prepare()</code> method.   Any size/location constraints specified by the labelDisplay
        define its location relative to the labelDisplayGroup.</p>

        <p>This value is specified with a <code>fx:Declaration</code> and can be overridden
        by a declaration with <code>id="labelDisplay"</code>
        in an MXML subclass.</p>


        @langversion 3.0
        @playerversion Flash 10
        @playerversion AIR 2.0
        @productversion Flex 4.5
        -->
        <s:Label id="labelDisplay" 
                 verticalCenter="1" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
                 textAlign="start"
                 fontWeight="bold"
                 verticalAlign="middle"
                 maxDisplayedLines="2"
                 showTruncationTip="true" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.gridClasses.IGridVisualElement;
            import mx.core.IVisualElement;

            import spark.components.DataGrid;
            import spark.components.GridColumnHeaderGroup;
            import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;

            /**
             *  @private
             */
            private function dispatchChangeEvent(type:String):void
            {
                if (hasEventListener(type))
                    dispatchEvent(new Event(type));
            }            

            //----------------------------------
            //  maxDisplayedLines
            //----------------------------------

            private var _maxDisplayedLines:int = 1;

            [Bindable("maxDisplayedLinesChanged")]
            [Inspectable(minValue="-1")]

            /**
             *  The value of this property is used to initialize the 
             *  <code>maxDisplayedLines</code> property of this renderer's 
             *  <code>labelDisplay</code> element.
             * 
             *  @copy spark.components.supportClasses.TextBase#maxDisplayedLines
             * 
             *  @default 1
             * 
             *  @langversion 3.0
             *  @playerversion Flash 10
             *  @playerversion AIR 1.5
             *  @productversion Flex 4.5
             */
            public function get maxDisplayedLines():int
            {
                return _maxDisplayedLines;
            }

            /**
             *  @private
             */
            public function set maxDisplayedLines(value:int):void
            {
                if (value == _maxDisplayedLines)
                    return;

                _maxDisplayedLines = value;
                if (labelDisplay)
                    labelDisplay.maxDisplayedLines = value;

                invalidateSize();
                invalidateDisplayList();

                dispatchChangeEvent("maxDisplayedLinesChanged");
            }

            //----------------------------------
            //  sortIndicator
            //----------------------------------

            private var _sortIndicator:IFactory;
            private var sortIndicatorInstance:IVisualElement;

            [Bindable("sortIndicatorChanged")]

            /**
             *  A visual element that's displayed when the column is sorted.
             * 
             *  <p>The sortIndicator visual element is added to the <code>sortIndicatorGroup</code>
             *  by this renderer's <code>prepare()</code> method.  Any size/location constraints 
             *  specified by the sortIndicator define its location relative to the sortIndicatorGroup.</p>
             * 
             *  @default null
             * 
             *  @langversion 3.0
             *  @playerversion Flash 10
             *  @playerversion AIR 1.5
             *  @productversion Flex 4.5
             */
            public function get sortIndicator():IFactory
            {
                return (_sortIndicator) ? _sortIndicator : defaultSortIndicator;
            }

            /**
             *  @private
             */
            public function set sortIndicator(value:IFactory):void
            {
                if (_sortIndicator == value)
                    return;

                _sortIndicator = value;
                if (sortIndicatorInstance)
                {
                    sortIndicatorGroup.includeInLayout = false;
                    sortIndicatorGroup.removeElement(sortIndicatorInstance);
                    sortIndicatorInstance = null;
                }

                invalidateDisplayList();
                dispatchChangeEvent("sortIndicatorChanged");
            }

            /**
             *  @private
             *  Create and add the sortIndicator to the sortIndicatorGroup and the 
             *  labelDisplay into the labelDisplayGroup.
             */
            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void
            {
                super.prepare(hasBeenRecycled);

                if (labelDisplay && labelDisplayGroup && (labelDisplay.parent != labelDisplayGroup))
                {
                    labelDisplayGroup.removeAllElements();
                    labelDisplayGroup.addElement(labelDisplay);
                }

                const column:GridColumn = this.column;
                if (sortIndicator && column && column.grid && column.grid.dataGrid && column.grid.dataGrid.columnHeaderGroup)
                {
                    const dataGrid:DataGrid = column.grid.dataGrid;
                    const columnHeaderGroup:GridColumnHeaderGroup = dataGrid.columnHeaderGroup;

                    if (columnHeaderGroup.isSortIndicatorVisible(column.columnIndex))
                    {
                        if (!sortIndicatorInstance)
                        {
                            sortIndicatorInstance = sortIndicator.newInstance();
                            sortIndicatorGroup.addElement(sortIndicatorInstance);
                        }

                        // Initialize sortIndicator
                        sortIndicatorInstance.visible = true;
                        const gridVisualElement:IGridVisualElement = sortIndicatorInstance as IGridVisualElement;
                        if (gridVisualElement)
                            gridVisualElement.prepareGridVisualElement(column.grid, -1, column.columnIndex);

                        sortIndicatorGroup.includeInLayout = true;
                        sortIndicatorGroup.scaleY = (column.sortDescending) ? 1 : -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (sortIndicatorInstance)
                        {
                            sortIndicatorGroup.removeElement(sortIndicatorInstance);
                            sortIndicatorGroup.includeInLayout = false;
                            sortIndicatorInstance = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="hovered" />
        <s:State name="down" />
    </s:states>      

    <!-- layer 1: shadow -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="shadow" left="-1" right="-1" top="-1" bottom="-1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 color.down="0xFFFFFF"
                                 alpha="0.01"
                                 alpha.down="0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 color.down="0xFFFFFF" 
                                 alpha="0.07"
                                 alpha.down="0.5" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 2: fill -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="fill" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" 
                                 color.hovered="0xBBBDBD" 
                                 color.down="0xAAAAAA" 
                                 alpha="0.85" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" 
                                 color.hovered="0x9FA0A1" 
                                 color.down="0x929496" 
                                 alpha="0.85" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 3: fill lowlight -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="lowlight" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="270">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.0" alpha="0.0627" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.48" alpha="0.0099" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.48001" alpha="0" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 4: fill highlight -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="highlight" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.0"
                                 alpha="0.33" 
                                 alpha.hovered="0.22" 
                                 alpha.down="0.12"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.48"
                                 alpha="0.33"
                                 alpha.hovered="0.22"
                                 alpha.down="0.12" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.48001"
                                 alpha="0" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>  

    <!-- layer 5: highlight stroke (all states except down) -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="highlightStroke" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" excludeFrom="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha.hovered="0.22" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" alpha.hovered="0.22" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 6: highlight stroke (down state only) -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="hldownstroke1" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" includeIn="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.25" ratio="0.0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.25" ratio="0.001" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.07" ratio="0.0011" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.07" ratio="0.965" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.00" ratio="0.9651" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="hldownstroke2" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" includeIn="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.09" ratio="0.0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.00" ratio="0.0001" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:HGroup left="7" right="7" top="5" bottom="5" gap="8" verticalAlign="middle">

        <s:BitmapImage source="54.gif" />
        <!-- layer 7: Container for labelDisplay:TextBase  -->
        <!--- Defines the size and location of the labelDisplay visual element. 

        <p>The <code>labelDisplay</code> is added to this Group by the renderer's 
        <code>prepare()</code> method.  Any size/location constraints
        specified by the labelDisplay
        define its layout relative to the labelDisplayGroup.</p>

        @langversion 3.0
        @playerversion Flash 10
        @playerversion AIR 2.0
        @productversion Flex 4.5
        -->
        <s:Group id="labelDisplayGroup" width="100%" />

        <!-- layer 8: Container for sortIndicator:IVisualElement  -->
        <!--- Defines the size and location of the sortIndicator visual element. 

        <p>The <code>sortIndicator</code> is added to this Group by the renderer's 
        <code>prepare()</code> method.  Any size/location constraints specified
        by the sortIndicator
        define its layout relative to the sortIndicatorGroup.  This Group is only
        included in the layout when the sortIndicator is visible.</p>  

        @langversion 3.0
        @playerversion Flash 10
        @playerversion AIR 2.0
        @productversion Flex 4.5
        -->
        <s:Group id="sortIndicatorGroup" includeInLayout="false" />
    </s:HGroup>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

And then to use it in your DataGrid, just follow Constantiner's example:

```
<s:DataGrid>
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn headerRenderer="MyRenderer" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Comment: @Constantiner, I totally missed the part about using the *Spark* data grid. Guess I'm going to have to head back to the drawing board! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use custom `headerRenderer` the following way:

```
<s:DataGrid>
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn headerRenderer="MyRenderer" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

The sample renderer with single-line header can be founded here `{flex4.5 SDK root}/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/skins/spark/DefaultGridHeaderRenderer.mxml`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see `headerRenderer` property of GridColumn in the sdk I am using so I could not accept the other answers. Here was my solution:

MultiLineColumnHeaderRenderer.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">  
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.supportClasses.GridColumn;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:TextArea editable="false" text="{(data as GridColumn).headerText}" />
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

An init function in the view with the datagrid:

```
        public function init():void{
            dataGrid.columnHeaderBar.firstItemRenderer = new ClassFactory(MultiLineColumnHeaderRenderer);
            dataGrid.columnHeaderBar.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(MultiLineColumnHeaderRenderer);
        }
```

And using `&#13;` in the `headerText` for the GridColumn:

```
<s:GridColumn headerText="Line1&#13;Line2&#13;Line2"/>
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I actually had the `&#13;` piece in my original answer and edited it out. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the DataGridSkin and place it in your source code. Then Edit Line 154 to this -

```
<fx:Component id="headerRenderer"> 
        <s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer  maxDisplayedLines="2"/>
</fx:Component>
```

Hope this helps,

Rich

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:
-Create a custom SparkDatagrid Skin creating a copy of the default one
-Create a custom DataGrid HeaderRenderer
-Just create a new GridItemRenderer (A) and put the code of the default   DataGridHeaderRenderer inside the new GridItemRenderer (A)
-Go into the label "labelDisplay" inside A and change its property "maxDisplayedLines" from 1 to 2
-Now return to you custom Spark Satagrid Skin and  search for the "headerRenderer" component.
-Replace it with an instance of your custom GridItemRender (A)

It worked for me...hope will do the same for you

mARCO

Answer (score 0):

Or,

if you don't want to create a new Renderer just for 1 propertie, you can just set the propertie like this :

```
...
<s:GridColumn width="100" dataField="myDataField" headerText="myHeaderText">
    <s:headerRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer maxDisplayedLines="2" />
        </fx:Component>
    </s:headerRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
...
```

if you look at the code inside the `DefaultGridHeaderRenderer` component, you'll see that when set, it change the value in the labelDisplay

But, if you have a lot of columns, and it can be boring to put the same code a lot of time, just create a new component which extends the spark Datagrid (or nests it depending of your need), then put the code :

```
public function set columns(value:IList):void
{
    for each (var gridColumn:GridColumn in value.toArray())
    {
        var headerRenderer:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(DefaultGridHeaderRenderer);
        headerRenderer.properties = {maxDisplayedLines: 2};
        gridColumn.headerRenderer = headerRenderer;
    }

    _columns = value;
}

[Bindable]
public function get columns():IList
{
    return _columns;
}
```